# checkbox :checked cambiar el color background jQuery

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/Chusi/w5gwdjac/5/

Como marcar el fondo a negro del *div* cuando el radio esté en *checked* , y solo un *div* a la vez pueda estar en negro JQuery.

El problema que tengo ahora es que los *div* se marcan con color negro, pero cuando marco uno al marcar el siguiente, el primero no vuelve al color inicial sino que se queda marcado con color negro.

Comment: El enlace al `JSFiddle` no funciona. Cambialo, y debido a eso, deberías añadir tu código directamente aquí.

Comment: hecho @cnbandicoot , Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes el código.

Simplemente cuando hagas un `on('change')` tienes que devolver todos los box a su estado original y al seleccionado darle los estilos que quieras darles.

https://jsfiddle.net/w5gwdjac/10/

añado: también puedes crear clases como "radioSelected" y así puedes tener el código aún más limpio y más "readable"

CSS:

```
.box.selected {
    background-color: #000;
}
.box.selected p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$input.each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(this).parent(".box").addClass("selected");
    }
});
$input.on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $input.each(function() {
            $(this).parent(".box").removeClass("selected");
        });
        $(this).parent(".box").addClass("selected");
    }
});
```

Comment: Funciona!
Creía que con tu recomendación de las _clases_ no funcionaba, pero sí, ya funciona!! :)  Gracias

Comment: De nada! Para eso estamos cuando nos proporcionan código. Y las clases por supuesto, cuando añadas o quitas una clase, el navegador lo renderiza si esta no tiene los atributos dados, o si es más especifica re-emplazando ya los existentes.